# How to create Form validation error message at runtime?

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have been searching for hours trying to find a way to validate my form while the user is typing. for example, I want have a field for zip code. I want the user to see a message underneath the field that says they have gone beyond the limit of characters for this field but before they submit the form. How can this be done?

with such code:

```
<form method="POST" name="wrriregistration" target="_blank"><center>
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="149"><strong>*First Name:</strong></td>
<td width="229"><input type="text" name="first_name" size="35" maxlength="100"/></td>
<td width="123"><strong style="display:none;">Middle Initial:</strong></td>
<td width="659"><input style="display:none;" type="text" name="middle_initial" size="35" maxlength="50" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: You will need javascript for that, it is not a php functionality.

Comment: The `maxlength` attribute will take care of users trying to enter too many characters. If it's validation that can be done just based on what's present on the form, you can just use simple Javascript to check the field using either they `keyup`, `keypress` or `change` events. If you need to validate against something on the back-end, you'll need to use AJAX.

Comment: Okay thank you. How so? Also could you explain why it is not php functionality?

Comment: PHP is a server-side language. It only works after you request a page and before you get HTML.

Comment: for complete form validation, u may see this. http://www.formvalidator.net/#reg-form

Comment: Thank you very much for that explanation. I am just getting into Web functionality as you could tell

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ty54t8r8/

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="first_name">
<div id="error">
    My custom error
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#error {
    display: none;
}

#error.show {
    display: block;
}

input {
    color: #000000;
}

.invalid {
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

**JS**

```
var input = document.querySelector('[name="first_name"]');
var error = document.getElementById('error');

input.addEventListener('keydown', function(){
    // Whatever you want
    if(this.value.length >= 10) {
        this.classList.add('invalid');
        // You can control style of your invalid input with .invalid
        error.classList.add('show'); // Display your custom error
    } else {
        this.classList.remove('invalid');
        error.classList.remove('show');
    }
});
```

**EDIT** Explanation :

`var input` target your first_name input

`addEventListener` makes a event detection. Passed with argument 'keydown', JavaScript will listen to keys pressed.

`classList` is an API to manipulate classes (not supported by IE).

Try it here : https://jsfiddle.net/e3oe4ykf/

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, I will try this out. I have read the above comment with this same implementation.

Comment: how can I get the length of one of those fields?

Comment: I am sorry but could you further explain how to implement? I've tried it many ways and cannot get it to run. I am just trying to warn users when character are surpassed on the name field